# How inject parameter in model constructor?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to use mutator to change price property before saving in database. I want to inject discount parameter and use it in mutator like below. I'm getting error "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'discount' in 'field list" Is it possible to inject parameter in model constructor?

```
 class Pizza2 extends Model
 {
   public $table = 'pizza2';
   public $timestamps = false;
   public $fillable = ['name', 'price'];

  public function __construct($d = null)
  {
    $this->discount = $d;
  }
public function setPriceAttribute($value)

{
    if ($this->discount) {
        $this->attributes['price'] = $value * $this->discount;
    } else {

        $this->attributes['price'] = $value;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Declare this discount as the protected variable of this model class and then its initialisation in constructor will work.

Comment: DI only works with defined types. What is your discount? Is it an object? And how would Laravel know where to find this discount?

Comment: It's working as protected variable. Thanks!

Comment: `$pizza2 = new Pizza2(0.2);`?